# is it possible to chain :first-child and :last-child pseudo class selectors?

Tags: html, css

i want to make the content in the paragraph tag to red color using `:first-child` and `:last-child`. can we achieve this by combining them both?
I tried to do this, but i am not getting the output!

```css
p :first-child:last-child{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            List of Car Brands
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>Honda</li>
            <li>Tesla</li>
            <li>Kia</li>

        </ul>
        <p>
            which one do you prefer?
        </p>
    </div>
       
        </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use comma to apply style to multiple selectors.

But you need to remove the whitespace between `p` and `:first-child` and use `p:first-child, p:last-child`

```css
p:first-child, p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    List of Car Brands
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Honda</li>
    <li>Tesla</li>
    <li>Kia</li>

  </ul>
  <p>
    which one do you prefer?
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can't. You can write instead

```
p:first-child, p:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```